# Best strategy to transfer photo files (bytes) from mobile device to web server?

Tags: file, networking, mobile, server, xamarin.forms

I am trying to solve an issue that impacts my app performance. I have a gallery app that user can select photos to build an album. Once the album is build the app transfers selected photos to the server. On the server side we expect 1200 x 400 /300DPI images. The server has functionality to resize and change the resolution of the photos before printing. My problem is with transferring photo files. For example IOS7 photos are  much bigger, so before transfer, I resize them to the expected size on the server and then gzip compress and send to server. Still this corresponds to 3-8 MB size transfers and it is too slow. What could be my options to make super fast transfers without loosing on photo quality that much.

Currently I use the the resize, compression, and http post.

Answer (score 1):

Well, those are speculations, but IMO your best option would be:

1. Use original jpeg photos, do not resize/gzip them, since it will be not that efficient as a jpeg compression.
2. Consider uploading a photo as soon as user selects/adds it to the album. So once the album is ready - you just send come control info and you are ready to go.